# Why is this mongodb query so slow?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have two collections, as follows:

**db.ships**
document format: { mmsi: Long, ...some other fields }
indexes: { {mmsi: 1}, {unique: true} }

**db.navUpdates**
document format: { mmsi: Long, time: ISODate, ...some other fields }
indexes: { mmsi: 1 }, { time: 1 }

For each document within `db.ships`, I need to find the most recent document within `db.navUpdates` that matches by `mmsi`.  I cannot use `_id` to find most recent as documents are not necessarily entered in chronological (as defined by timestamp `time`) order.

E.g.:

```
ship document:
{ mmsi: 12345 }

navUpdate documents:
{ mmsi: 12345, time: ISODate("2012-09-19T12:00:00.000Z") }
{ mmsi: 12345, time: ISODate("2012-09-18T12:00:00.000Z") }
{ mmsi: 54321, time: ISODate("2012-09-19T12:00:00.000Z") }
```

So for the `ship` with `mmsi:12345`, the most recent `navUpdate` is the first document in the list above, with `time:ISODate("2012-09-19T12:00:00.000Z")`.

I tried the following mongo shell script, but it's incredibly slow (multiple seconds for just 10 queries), and [messages appearing on the server indicate I'm missing an index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758377/mongodb-geting-client-cursoryield-cant-unlock-b-c-of-recursive-lock-warnin).

```
db.ships.find().limit(10).forEach(function(ship) {
    var n = db.navUpdates.find({mmsi:ship.mmsi}).count();
    if (n==0) { return; }
    var t = db.navUpdates.find({mmsi:ship.mmsi}).sort({time:-1}).limit(1)[0].time;
    print(t);
});
```

Why is this query so slow?  I tried adding a `{time: -1}` index to `navUpdate`, thinking perhaps the `sort({time: -1})` might be the culprit, but still no improvement.

Also, can this query be optimized?  I have the `count()` call in there because there are some `ship` documents whose `mmsi`s are not found within `navUpdates`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single query can only use one index, so you should add a compound index of `{ mmsi: 1, time: -1 }`  to `navUpdates` that can be used for both your find and sort needs.

Then use [`.explain()`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Explain) to determine if your indexes are being used in your queries.

Comment: Ah, so each of the documents returned by `find({mmsi})` must be traversed to examine its `time` value, and then `sort()`ed.  Makes sense.  Will `sort({time:-1})` be able to take advantage of an index with `{time:1}`?  (Does order matter for this `sort()`?)

Comment: Answer to my comment: order does not matter in this case.  When I `sort({time:-1})`, `explain()`  reveals the use of `"cursor" : "BtreeCursor mmsi_1_time_1 reverse"`.