# MongoDB 3.6 ClientCursor :: staticYield can't unlock b/c of recursive lock ns:

Tags: java, mongodb, logging, indexing

Our prod mongo server is running out of memory with excessive logging of below statement

```
2018-03-19T20:03:05.627-0500 [conn2] warning: ClientCursor::staticYield can't unlock b/c of recursive lock ns:

    top:{  
       opid:16,
       active:true,
       secs_running:0,
       microsecs_running:254,
       op:"query",
       ns:"users.person",
       query:{  
          findandmodify:"person",
          query:{  
             clientSN:"405F014DE02B33F1",
             status:"New"
          },
          update:{  
             $set:{  
                status:"InProcess"
             },
             $currentDate:{  
                lastUpdateTime:true
             }
          },
          new:true
       },
       client:"10.102.26.26:61299",
       desc:"conn2",
       connectionId:2,
       locks:{  
          ^:"w",
          ^users:"W"
       },
       waitingForLock:false,
       numYields:0,
       lockStats:{  
          timeLockedMicros:{  

          },
          timeAcquiringMicros:{  
             r:0,
             w:1070513
          }
       }
    }
```

I have checked the [MongoDB: How to disable logging the warning: ClientCursor::staticYield can't unlock b/c of recursive lock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24911469/mongodb-how-to-disable-logging-the-warning-clientcursorstaticyield-cant-unl) which suggests cause of the issue is missing indexes.

I tried runnign the query with `explain()` as per the above article and Below is the output of `db.getCollection('personSync').find({"clientSN":"405F014DE02B33F1","status":"New"}).explain()` the query which has the fields of above `findandmodify` operation

```
{
    "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 0,
    "nscannedObjects" : 71331,
    "nscanned" : 71331,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 71331,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 71331,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 557,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 59,
    "server" : "SQL01:27017",
    "filterSet" : false,
    "stats" : {
        "type" : "COLLSCAN",
        "works" : 71333,
        "yields" : 557,
        "unyields" : 557,
        "invalidates" : 0,
        "advanced" : 0,
        "needTime" : 71332,
        "needFetch" : 0,
        "isEOF" : 1,
        "docsTested" : 71331,
        "children" : []
    }
}
```

so I was referring to article on https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/ to create index, would adding index in below way fix my issue for `findandmodify` operation in my case? Or do I need to add any more indexes too?

```
db.users.createIndex({ clientSN:"405F014DE02B33F1", status:"New"})
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the index should improve the performance of this operation. Currently it's performing a Collection Scan; using an index will be much more efficient.

The createIndex command is incorrect. It should be the following:

```
db.users.createIndex({ clientSN:1, status:1}, { background : true } )
```

Note that indexes are built in the foreground by default, so setting the  [background](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/#options-for-all-index-types) flag is very important.